# Storing the previous month as a char with a leading 0 for single digit months

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a field filled with dates, but they are stored as varchars. They are in the following format:

- 01312013
- 01302013
- 09232007

I am trying to write a query that only returns records that meet the following three criteria:

- The last four characters of the aforementioned varchar "date" match **the year** of the previous month
- The first two characters of the aforementioned varchar "date" match the previous month.
- The value in an entirely different date field (that is actually stored as a date) falls within the previous month

My attempts have left me trying to store the year of the previous month and the previous month in two variables, and then perform a LEFT() and RIGHT() lookup on the varchar "date" to see if they match those two variables. Whew.

The problem is that the MONTH is getting stored as a single digit, and I need to store it as a "0" + the month digit (in the case of single digit months only). Also it's not even working for just the year so maybe this is completely off. Really hope someone can help!

Here's what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @monthAgo dateTime
DECLARE @MonthString char
DECLARE @YearString char

SET @monthAgo = DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
SET @MonthString = MONTH(@monthAgo) -- not working
SET @YearString = YEAR(@monthAgo) -- not working

SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    jwemaildb.LogFileRecords
WHERE
    date > = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) AND
    date <  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND
    RIGHT(eAlertSentDate, 4) = @YearString AND
    LEFT (eAlertSentDate, 2) = @MonthString
```

Comment: Fortunately you can cast those strings as dates, unless you have some strange values, such as 'oh dear'.  Then it's a simple dateadd().

Comment: @DanBracuk - I would suggest that as an answer!  With a bit of error checking, even the 'oh dear' could be handled.

Comment: Yes my 'oh dear' situation is realized - the parameter that this date is culled from sometimes comes out wonky in the logs and there is a bunch of text in the fields. I need to figure out a work around for that now! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you need convert varchar "date" into ISO standard

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM jwemaildb.LogFileRecords
WHERE
    date > = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) AND
    date <  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND
    CAST(RIGHT(eAlertSentDate, 4) + LEFT(eAlertSentDate, 4) AS date) BETWEEN       
    DATEADD(dd , 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), DATEADD(mm, -1 ,GETDATE())) AND
    DATEADD(dd , 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE())
```

Simple demo on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11338)

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately you can cast those strings as dates, unless you have some strange values, such as 'oh dear'. Then it's a simple dateadd().

Just to make sure it works:

```
 declare @dateString as char(8);
 set @dateString = '02132013';

 select cast(left(@dateString, 2) + '/' + 
 substring(@dateString, 3,2) +'/' +   
 right(@dateString, 4) as date) theDate;
```

returns

```
theDate
2013-02-13
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I do indeed have a character string in that data. This points me in the right direction though. I'll look into figuring out error handling those cases or figuring out how to ignore those records (which I don't want to count anyway). Any tips would be appreciated.